# 10-eth0.network

Tags: linux, ethernet, systemd-networkd

I was trying to ping my machine from a photon OS IP but wasn't able to do so. So I followed a post and changed the `/etc/systemd/network/10-eth0.network` to the following:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Domains=HOSTNAME domain.local
Gateway=1xxx.xxx.x.x
Address=1xx.xxx.x.xxx
DHCP=no

[DHCP]
UseDomains=false
```

Now I can't even login. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: I noticed you don't have a NETMASK or PREFIX defined for the interface. I'm not familiar with every type of init script for networking on *NIX, but I do know that most of the time it is important (necessary?) to have one of these defined, so the interface knows how to send broadcast traffic... particularly if you are on a network with [supernetting/CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

Comment: I just want to reset it to the old configuration. Is there a way to do that now? I can't even login to the host now. This is on photon-os.

Comment: I don't see how you can edit the config if you can't login to the system. Do you have access to the virtual-console of the system (I assume it is a VM, since it is PhotonOS).

Comment: This site is more or less the right one. They vary (serverfault is for "professional" system administrators, and covers *NIX, Windows, and others. I'm more active here because I'm a unix nerd at heart.) In my last i meant "if you can't login, you will not be able to edit the file." You appear to have effectively disabled the networking, so you will not be able to make any changes remotely. If this is a VM, and if you have access to the console (virtual console, on a real computer it would be the keyboard/mouse/screen), you could make the edits and try to restart the network.

Comment: You are a life saver. I was able to login to the VM and revert my changes. THANK YOU. 1. If you want you can answer the question and I will go ahead and accept it. 2. I need to be able to ping my local ip from this machine, can you please tell me how I can go about it? It works from my office network, but not from home. Any help, again is much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93190/discussion-between-0xsheepdog-and-nicholas-k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not appear to have configured a NETMASK or PREFIX value for your interface. While not clearly explained often, a proper address actually requires this information.

If you can no longer remotely connect via SSH, Telnet, etc. to the VM, you will need to logon to the console of the system:

- physical computer will require access to the monitor, keyboard, mouse, etc.
- virtual machine will require access to the 'virtual console', which can vary greatly depending on the virtualization technology in use

Once on the console, you need to login and modify the network configuration file to include all necessary parameters. Please refer to the PhotonOS documentation (man pages is probably sufficient) to be sure, but at the minimum I believe a NETMASK value is required.